# use of copyArtifactPermission for multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using more than one agents in my declarative pipeline. i am trying  copy artifacts (input.txt) from agent1 to agent2 in same pipeline from last stage? in below code you can see i am giving permission by using copyArtifactPermission to main branch but as i am using multi branch pipeline, i need to give permission to all my branches. how can we define that ?

```
    agent none

    options {
        copyArtifactPermission('main');
    }


    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent { label 'agent1' }
            steps {
                sh 'echo arjun > input.txt'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'input.txt', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            agent { label 'agent2' }
            steps {
                // this brings artifacts from job named as this one, and this build
                step([
                        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                        filter: 'input.txt',
                        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                        optional: true,
                        projectName: env.BRANCH_NAME,
                        selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                                   buildNumber: env.BUILD_NUMBER]
                ])

                sh 'cat input.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you needing to copy artifacts between different builds of different branches/PRs of the same multibranch pipeline _job_, or simply between different agents within a single _build_ of a single branch/PR? E.g., would you want artifacts from `main` #5 be accessible to `PR-235` #8, or just artifacts from `agent1` within, say, `main` build #5 to be accessible to `agent2` in that same build?

Comment: Have you already figure it out ? I need exactly the same.
I have multibranch pipeline and last stage runs on other agent and I would like to download artifact from previous stage. Is there any way to use copyArtifact plugin for this ?